# Code compiles on g++ with warning but gives error for same code on clang3.1(Xcode 4.3.3)

Tags: c++, macos

Following line compiles successfully on g++ but gives error on clang::

```
static_assert(tBits <= sizeof(ULONG)*8, "This is IO method");
```

g++ warning ::

> there are no arguments to 'static_assert' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'static_assert' must be available

clang error ::

> use of undeclared identifier 'static_assert'; did you mean 'static_cast'?

please help me out.

Function declaration from comment:

```
template < size_t tBits >
HRESULT DoIO( std::bitset< tBits >& bitsetToSerialize ) const
```

Comment: Are you building with C++11 enabled? I.e. `-std=c++11`. Also, how is `tBits` declared?

Comment: c++11 is enabled and  tBits is template which is defined as                                                             template < size_t tBits > HRESULT DoIO( std::bitset< tBits >& bitsetToSerialize ) const

Comment: Use __has_feature(cxx_static_assert) or __has_extension(cxx_static_assert) to determine if support for compile-time assertions using static_assert is enabled.  Ref: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cxx_static_assert

Answer (score 2):

"static_assert" was introduced in C++11 as a language keyword - not a function or a macro.

Both compilers are giving you the "I don't know this function" warnings/errors.

For the compiler to give you "I don't know this function" when you are using "static_assert", the compiler must not be compiling with C++11 support (-std=c++11).

To demonstrate this, I took the following piece of code:

```
#include <bitset>

template<size_t tBits>
int DoIO(std::bitset<tBits>& /*bitsetToSerialize*/)
{
    static_assert(tBits <= sizeof(unsigned long) * 8, "tBits is too big.");
    return tBits;
}
```

Then I compiled it with GCC 4.7.3 and I got the following error:

```
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $ g++ -o sa.o -c sa.cpp
sa.cpp: In function ‘int DoIO(std::bitset<_Nb>&)’:
sa.cpp:6:78: error: there are no arguments to ‘static_assert’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘static_assert’ must be available [-fpermissive]
sa.cpp:6:78: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

Then I compiled it with C++11 support enabled and it compiled without a problem:

```
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $ g++ -std=c++11 -o sa.o -c sa.cpp -Wall
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $
```

So, then I compiled it with Clang

```
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $ clang++ -o sa.o -c sa.cpp
sa.cpp:6:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'static_assert'; did you mean 'static_cast'?
        static_assert(tBits <= sizeof(unsigned long) * 8, "tBits is too big.");
        ^
1 error generated.
```

and finally I compiled it using Clang with C++11 support, where it compiled fine.

```
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $ clang++ -std=c++11 -o sa.o -c sa.cpp
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $
```

Just to be sure, let's give the compiler opportunity to help us and turn on "-Wall":

```
osmith@olivia64 ~/src $ g++ -Wall -o sa.o -c sa.cpp
sa.cpp:6:9: warning: identifier ‘static_assert’ is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]
sa.cpp: In function ‘int DoIO(std::bitset<_Nb>&)’:
sa.cpp:6:78: error: there are no arguments to ‘static_assert’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘static_assert’ must be available [-fpermissive]
sa.cpp:6:78: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```